# Is it possible for firefox's awesome bar to search my stackoverflow favourites (bookmarks)?

Tags: discussion, search, firefox

This question is related specifically to Firefox so not sure if this is the right place to ask.  I would like to search stack type sites favourites such as stackoverflow, by just typing in firefox's awesome bar and have it treat my stackoverflow favourites like bookmarks, but without having to manually sync them i.e. favourite in stackoverflow and bookmark in firefox.

I have seen it is possible to add the search engine stackoverflow and search infavorites:mine , but this requires switching from my default of google to stackoverflow search engine which gets annoying when you quickly want to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [keyword search](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html) to add a custom search for Stack Overflow favorites:

1. Bookmark the URL

   https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3Amine+%s
2. In the bookmark dialog, give this bookmark a keyword. `sofavs` for example.

[image: keyword on bookmark]

Now you can search for favorites with:

```
sofavs search query
```

in your Awesome Bar. Firefox finds the bookmark by the keyword, then replaces the `%s` placeholder with the search query, and loads that URL.

Comment: That is probably as close as I will find to a solution for this, unless there is some plugin API for the awesome bar, thanks.